# What is the proper way of returning a new instance of an immutable?

Tags: c++, immutability

I would like to leave the two instances unchanged, and return a new one.
Currently I am doing it this way:

```
class myClass {

    public:

        myClass operator +(const myClass &obj) {

            myClass ret = *this;

            // some operation

            return ret;

        }

        // functions...

};
```

It works, but I am not sure, if it is the correct way

---

**Edit**

The `operator +` is just an example. I'm just curious, how the immutable functions/methods should be written in C++

Comment: Why are you unsure?  It does what you want right?

Comment: I believe there's nothing wrong with what you wrote

Comment: I am unsure, because I'm just a beginner, and I've created this code by myself

Comment: @NathanOliver Lot's of things that appear to do what you want might be 1. UB, 2. bad practice, with downsides you haven't thought of yet. However, it does make for a bit of a vague/open-ended question for SO. That said, in this case, I believe this is a reasonable approach.

Comment: Looks fine. Personally I'd write a comment for the first line, indicating explicitly that the copy constructor is being invoked. Or, just invoke the appropriate constructor directly. For example, if `myClass` represented an integer, you could either write what you have now: `myClass ret = *this; ret.value += other.value;`, or you could avoid the copy and construct a new one straight away with `myClass ret(this->value + other.value)`.

Comment: @BoBTFish That is what I was getting at.  I was hoping the OP would add a little more to the question.

Comment: You're missing one thing: the function should be `const`. `myClass operator +(const myClass &obj) const`.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myClass` is supposed to be immutable under addition, you probably want to make `operator+` a free function rather than a class member.  (You might have to make it a friend function.)

```
myClass operator+(const myClass &lhs, const myClass &rhs) {
  return myClass( /* some operation */ );
}
```

Note that both operands are taken by const reference, so you know you cannot accidentally change them (maintaining the immutability property).  You're returning a new instance of `myClass`, which is now immutable.  You construct and return the result in one step, because, if `myClass` really is immutable, you might not be able to default construct one and then set its value.

Here's a stupid example:

```
class myClass {
  public:
    explicit myClass(int x) : m_x(x) {}
    friend myClass operator+(const myClass &lhs, const myClass &rhs);
  private:
    int m_x;
};

myClass operator+(const myClass &lhs, const myClass &rhs) {
  return myClass(lhs.m_x + rhs.m_x);
}
```

If you really want to implement it as a class method, the method should be marked const to ensure the implementation doesn't accidentally mutate the left-hand instance.

Binary arithmetic operators (like `operator+`) are often defined in terms of the arithmetic self-assignment operators (like `operator+=`), which are obviously not immutable.  If we add this method to `myClass`:

```
myClass &operator+=(const myClass &rhs) {
  m_x += rhs.m_x;
  return *this;
}
```

Then the common idiom for defining `operator+` would be:

```
myClass operator+(const myClass &lhs, const myClass &rhs) {
  myClass result = lhs;
  result += rhs;
  return result;
}
```

Now the implementation of `operator+` doesn't require any of the private members of the class, so it no longer needs to be declared as a friend function.